# Best way to avoid 'control reaches end of non-void function' warning in release mode

Tags: c++, return-value, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I have a class (here `MyObject`) with a function returning a name by refererence depending on the internal type of the object. Moreover, this function can only be called for some values of the internal type.

```
/**
 * \brief Return the name depending of the internal type
 * \pre   The internal type must be 1 or 2
 */
inline
const std::string& MyObject::getName() const
{
  switch(this->type)
  {
    case 1:
      return this->type1->getName();
      break;
    case 2:
      return this->type2->getName();
      break;
    default:
      assert(false && "PRE: Invalid type for this operation");
  }
}
```

Then, when I compile in Release mode, I get this warning :

> warning: control reaches end of non-void function

**What is the best way to avoid this warning in this case ?** I can't return an empty string, because it will result in a reference to a temporary object, and then another warning. I prefer to not throw an exception in this context, because it's only to solve the warning. If the execution calls the default part, it's a programming bug, it will be detect in Debug mode in pre-prod with the assertion. Normally, the execution never calls it in Release mode, and it's acceptable to have a undefined behaviour in this case.

Comment: I don't see any good reason to not throw an exception.

Comment: Note that "undefined behaviour" isn't "random behaviour" - having it makes the entire program undefined, and a very aggressive optimiser may assume that `this->type` never has a value other than 1 or 2.

Comment: `exception` or `abort()` or redesign to avoid the switch case.

Comment: @juanchopanza: I don't want exception for this function because it's called in a destructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can return the reference of a static variable:

```
/**
 * \brief Return the name depending of the internal type
 * \pre   The internal type must be 1 or 2
 */
inline
const std::string& MyObject::getName() const
{
  switch(this->type)
  {
    case 1:
      return this->type1->getName();
      break;
    case 2:
      return this->type2->getName();
      break;
    default:
      assert(false && "PRE: Invalid type for this operation");
  }

  static std::string hack("");
  return hack;
}
```

Comment: In this case, it's probably a good solution. If unfortunatelly the bug is still present in Release mode, I prefer it return a wrong name than stopping the program.

Comment: I think so too. I my opinion handling the error internally is better than aborting the program.

Answer (score 4):

> "...it's acceptable to have a random behaviour in this case."

It may be acceptable, but why would you want to?  Just add an `exit(1);` after the `assert` and you wouldn't be spending time on here, or write a macro to add both `assert` and `exit`.

Separately, you don't need to `break` from `case`s that `return`.

Comment: Yeah, the `break`'s are a good practice. It's a quite common complex bug to solve when you forgot one of them.

Comment: @Caduchon: I totally disagree... it obfuscates the `return` which was already adequate, and invites incorrect reasoning like *"I'll remove this `break` and let `case` X fall through"* - but it won't because it's already `return`ed.